# QGIS: Draw CompoundCurveZ by elevation in 2D

Tags: qgis, 3d

I have a CompoundCurveZ layer in QGIS with Curves that overlap when seen in 2D. Mock Example without Curve:

```
ID     geometry
----   ------------------------------
1      LineStringZ(5,0,5,5,5,5,10,5,5)
2      LineStringZ(0,3,0,6,3,0,6,6,100)
```

The resulting 2D view looks like this:

[image: Line 1 purple, Line 2 red]

I would like to represent these features in 2D depending on their z value, so 1 crosses above 2 at the 2D Intersection `(5,3)` but below 2 at the 2D intersection `(6,5)` Is that possible and if yes, how?